# driver.get is not navigating to the url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently when i use

```
def testGooglePM(self):
    print "\n Searching for article "
    d = self.driver.getDriver()
    d.get('www.google.com')
```

it opens a new firefox window but does not navigate to the url

Answer (score 5):

I believe Firefox `WebDriver` has issues with bare URLs.  Try this instead:

```
d.get('https://www.google.com')
```